# Why is my django form many-to-many field giving me this error?

Tags: python, django

I strongly suspect that this boils down to me needing to understand some language construct better, but I don't know where to start, so I'm just going to have to throw some code out.

models:

```
class BlogTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(BlogTag)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

form:

```
class BlogForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogEntry
```

view:

```
title='New Blog Entry'
if request.method=='POST':
    form=BlogForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd=form.cleaned_data
        blogEntry=BlogEntry(**cd)
        blogEntry.save()
else:
    form=BlogForm();
return render_to_response('blog_add.html', locals())
```

By using **cd I was able to take the cleaned data directly into my object, which is obviously desireable because this way the view is loosely coupled to the other objects -- I can change the model, and everything else changes with it without me having to do a thing.

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error that:

```
'tags' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I could always break down the CD and build a manual dictionary approach of blogEntry=BlogEntry(title=cd['title']...) and then just add the tags in one by one, but...  I should have better options than that, and I just don't know what they are :(

Comment: Well, I just noticed in the documentation that I was making my life more difficult than it had to me -- I could just call .save() on the actual form with no worries.  Which suggests that cleaning the data to create a form is probably not necessary, and so has limited support.

Comment: When you call form.is_valid() on a _ModelForm_ it triggers validation on both the form and model level; which is why you don't need to - in normal circumstances - manually clean the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what it boils down to is that `**cd` will pass in the arguments as a dictionary. `BlogEntry` is expecting a `BlogTag` type for `tags` instead you are passing it the dictionary argument which is not the right type. First create a `BlogTag` object and then pass that in to `BlogEntry`

This might help http://anubis.blasux.ru/books/Python/www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/models/many_to_many/

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to know how exactly I was tripping over something even if I'd figured out how to bypass the issue in question.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BlogForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        blogEntry = form.save()
        # redirect ..

else:
    form = BlogForm()

context = {
    "form": form,
    # ...
}
return render_to_response('blog_add.html', context)
```

PS, `locals()` is bad form and http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: A) Why is locals() bad form -- the tutorial I'm using suggested it! and B) that's a long piece of documentation to throw at someone without suggesting why it's being thrown (since I already appear to be following it in most cases, and the one case where I'm not -- tabs -- my style is listed as an option, if not the top preferred option)

Comment: spaces around '=' for assignment, spaces around '==', no semicolon at the end of the line, 4 spaces is standard instead of tabs (I didn't notice the tabs)... maybe the locals thing is a style choice ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901525/django-template-and-the-locals-trick ) ... I see it in the Django book. I think back to old code with locals() as the template context and shudder though, personally.

Comment: Hilariously, the one and only one semicolon that's slipped past my attempts to censor my reflexive use of the character (strong C and PHP background as my primary coding languages) and it's in the code I pasted.  I'll work on the spaces more (again, it's a habit developed while working in other environments, though without the excuse of it being required).  As for the locals() thing, I was focused on the DRY factor (which is why I love it so much), but I can also see the coupling issues it creates for refactoring.

Comment: If I can ask... why do people like spaces so much when a single 'tab' press is so much quicker and easier?

Comment: I configure my editor to make 4 spaces when I hit tab. As to why, I don't have a great argument. Spaces work for everything, no matter the editor, revision control system, etc, everything always looks the same with spaces .. tabs on the other hand can be interpreted differently by different tools. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119562/tabs-versus-spaces-in-python-programming - it just is.