# Django using locals()

Tags: python, django

I am beginner in web development with Django. I have noticed that the `locals()` function is used instead of the context dictionary that I am used to see.

From what I see on the internet `locals()` is pretty useful, so are there any special cases where this is not true and its better to use the `context_dictionary`?

Comment: Try to avoid locals() as Views Context. It has been stated many times to be an anti-pattern http://stackoverflow.com/a/1901720/2115494 .

Comment: @SuburbanFilth, I have added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `locals()` in that tutorial is just for convenience, since all the data he needs to pass to the template is stored in local variables. `locals()` returns a dictionary holding the local variables names (as keys) and the current values (as values).

You need to use an explicit context_dictionary, instead of passing `locals()`, if you must build your data and you don't have such data in separate variables.

both `locals()` and context_dictionary are dictionaries, and that's the only requirement: a dictionary-like object (i.e. an object supporting `__getitem__(key)` and `get(key, default=None)` methods). How you get the dictionary, is up to you. There's no practice about that, but alternatives are:

- Return a `RequestContext()`, which is a dict-like object, if you use `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.
- Return `locals()` if you have the data in your local variables.
- Return a hand-made dictionary with your data otherwise.

**EDIT** - Examples:

Example on building the dictionary on your own:

```
def my_view(request):
    return render_to_response('hello.html', {
        'full_name': u"%s %s" % (request.user.first_name, request.user.last_name),
        'username': request.user.username
    })
```

Example on building the dictionary from `locals()`:

```
def my_view(request):
    full_name = u"%s %s" % (request.user.first_name, request.user.last_name)
    username = request.user.username

    return render_to_response('hello.html', locals())
```

Assume hello.html is - in either case:

```
<html>
    <body>
        You are {{ full_name }} ({{ username }})
    </body>
</html>
```

You'll get the expected result.

Comment: I am sorry for the ignorance, but can you give me an example of 'if you must build your data and you don't have such data in separate variables.'?

Answer (score 2):

if your view looks something like this:

```
def myview(request):
    thing = 1
    name = 'fred'
    stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and in your template you want to do:

```
{{ thing }} of {{ name }} has {% for x in stuff %}{{ x }}{% endfor %}
```

then in the view you could:

```
    return render(request, 'template.html', locals())
```

This is because `locals()` returns a dict of all the locally defined variables in the current scope. So it's kind of a sneaky shortcut.

Be careful though, since you are likely to expose more values than you intend to... generally we'd prefer the "Explicit is better than implicit" approach from the [Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) i.e. define a dict containing only what you want to pass through to the template.

```
def myview(request):
    context = {
       'thing': 1,
       'name': 'fred',
    }
    # do more code...
    context['stuff'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by context dictionary is the named arguments? If yes, they're different, locals shows you all the locals variables, kwargs dictionary instead shows only the named arguments.

```
def test(**kwargs):
   c = 'abc'
   print kwargs
   print locals()

test(a=10, b=20)
```

The first print shows: {'a': 10, 'b': 20} while the second one shows: {'c': 'abc', 'kwargs': {'a': 10, 'b': 20}}

Comment: in the context of Django a 'context dictionary' is the dict of value passed from the view to the template for rendering

Answer (score 0):

`locals()` is a Python built-in function that according to the official Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

> Updates and returns a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. Free variables are returned by `locals()` when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks.

Example:

```
In [1]: def f():
   ...:     a = 1
   ...:     b = 2
   ...:     c = 'three'
   ...:
   ...:     return locals()
   ...:

In [2]: f()
Out[2]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 'three'}
```

I think `locals()` might be useful to **avoid repetition** when you are going to create a dictionary with the variables you have defined in the view (probably most or all variables you have created are going to be included in the context dictionary).

However, using `locals()` *is not beneficial for refactoring*. The local variables of a view can freely be changed when performing a refactoring. Then, you cannot safely rename a variable because they don't have a visible effect. Another problem you could also experience is *performance* because you will probably include variables that you don't really need in the context, and in case your view is declaring lots of temporal variables, the context will be overloaded.

Therefore, it might be a good idea to avoid `locals()`.