# Django can't display data from two models

Tags: django

I am trying to display data from two different models. The two models have a one-to-many relationship but I am not sure why it is not displaying the data from the MembersPresent model. Here are my models
and view

```html
class fly_minute(models.Model):
    mode = (
        ('Email', 'Email'),
        ('Zoom', 'Zoom'),
        ('Alternative', 'Alternative'),
    )
    mode_of_meeting = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=mode, blank=False, )
    date = models.DateField()
    Time = models.TimeField()
    minute_prepared_by = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    authorize_by = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    item = models.TextField()
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.mode_of_meeting


class MembersPresent(models.Model):
    flyminute = models.ForeignKey(fly_minute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=25)
    phone = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```html
@login_required(login_url='login_page')
def MinutesReport(request, minute_id):
    report = fly_minute.objects.filter(id=minute_id)
    return render(request, 'minute_report.html', locals())
    
    
    
 
 {%for rpt in report%}

    <tbody>
      <tr class="table-active">

        <td>{{rpt.flyminute.name}}</td>
        <td>{{rpt.flyminute.status}}</td>
          <td>{{rpt.flyminute.email}}</td>
          <td>{{rpt.flyminute.phone}}</td>


    </tbody>
    {%endfor%}
```

Comment: Can you share a code of `locals` function?

Comment: `locals()` function returns all the variables defined in that view. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25063474/12420884) for more clarity

Comment: Did you check if the `report` contains any data?

Comment: It will be better to use the correct class, method naming conventions classes should be UpperCamelCase and methods in python should be all simple cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ['prefetch_related()'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

> Returns a QuerySet that will automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.
> This has a similar purpose to select_related, in that both are designed to stop the deluge of database queries that is caused by accessing related objects, but the strategy is quite different.

models.py

```
class MembersPresent(models.Model):
    flyminute = models.ForeignKey(
        fly_minute,
        related_name='memberspresent_set',  # this will be the default name, incase of need of change provide a new one
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    ...
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login_page')
def MinutesReport(request, minute_id):
    report = fly_minute.objects.filter(id=minute_id).prefetch_related('memberpresent_set')
    return render(request, 'minute_report.html', locals())
```

For further control, you can use [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) along with `prefetch_related()`

---

**Note**:

`locals()` returns a dict of all the locally defined variables in the current scope and this may result in exposing sensitive info. Instead of that create a custom dict and return it.

```
...
context = {
    'report': report,
     ...
}

return render(request, 'minute_report.html', context)
```

Comment: I try that but I get this error:  Cannot find 'memberspresent_set' on fly_minute object, 'memberspresent_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: oops sorry, the related_name should be `membersrelated` I've updated my answer ,views.py

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing and querying in the opposite way. Your `fly_minute` model doesn't contain `MembersPresent` model as the Foreign Key. You are filtering the `fly_minute` model and trying to access `MembersPresent` model. So, you should change your `fly_minute` to in this way:

```
class fly_minute(models.Model):
    mode = (
        ('Email', 'Email'),
        ('Zoom', 'Zoom'),
        ('Alternative', 'Alternative'),
    )
    mode_of_meeting = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=mode, blank=False, )
    date = models.DateField()
    Time = models.TimeField()
    minute_prepared_by = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    authorize_by = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    item = models.TextField()
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    member = models.ForeignKey(MembersPresent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)#add this line and remove fly_minute in MembersPresent model
    def __str__(self):
        return self.mode_of_meeting
```

Then in template file change it to in this way:

```
{%for rpt in report%}

    <tbody>
      <tr class="table-active">

        <td>{{rpt.member.name}}</td>
        <td>{{rpt.member.status}}</td>
          <td>{{rpt.member.email}}</td>
          <td>{{rpt.member.phone}}</td>


    </tbody>
    {%endfor%}
```

I guess it works

Comment: You're changing the relationship between the two models and this is entirely wrong and against basic DB relationship rules(1:m foreignkey). BTW  the op didn't mention clearly the relationships either.

Comment: He didn't mention relationships but, I assumed he wants to reference one model with another. He referenced `fly_minute` model in  `MembersPresent` and tried to access `MembersPresent` using the data from the fly_minute model. I guess it is not possible. And suggested him to change the relationships defined in the model as from the view he wrote, I assumed he want to get `fly_minute` from the `MembersPresent` model

Comment: It's possible using `prefetch_related()`, btw you have to ask the op for further clarification before assuming :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I ended up using fetch-related and had to make adjustments to my template.

```html
      <tr>

        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
        {%for rpt in report%}
    {%for rpts in rpt.memberspresent_set.all%}

    <tbody>
      <tr class="table-active">

        <td>{{rpts.name}}</td>
        <td>{{rpts.status}}</td>
          <td>{{rpts.email}}</td>
          <td>{{rpts.phone}}</td>


    </tbody>
    {%endfor%}
        {%endfor%}
```

Comment: it's better to update the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66741119/8388057), with the template part