# Django 1.11 context must be a dict rather than RequestContext

Tags: python, django

I am writing a login page with Django 1.11. and this is what I received:

> context must be a dict rather than `RequestContext`.

This is my code:

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse

def login(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')

    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('login.html', RequestContext(request, locals()))
```

And this is my template:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="username">用戶名稱:</label>{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{username}}" id="username"><br />
        <label for="password">用戶密碼:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="登入" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you using Django 1.1? That's nine years old and totally insecure. Upgrade to 1.11 or 2.0 immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the warning. I am using Django 1.11. It was an typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use `render_to_response`, it’s obsolete. Use the `render` shortcut instead.

```
return render(request, 'login.html', locals())
```

Note that Django comes with a login view, you don’t have to write your own. It’s not recommended to use `locals()` because it’s harder to see what is in the template context.

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.11 prohibits non-dict context.

> For compatibility with multiple template engines, `django.template.backends.django.Template.render()` must receive a dictionary of context rather than Context or RequestContext. If you were passing either of the two classes, pass a dictionary instead – doing so is backwards-compatible with older versions of Django.

`render()` is a brand-new shortcut for `render_to_response` in Django 1.3 that will automatically use `RequestContext`. Thus, as @Alasdair has told you, *Don’t use `render_to_response()`, it’s obsolete. Use the `render()` shortcut instead.*

Therefore, your code should be as follows:

```
def login(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')

    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', locals())
```

I should also add that I am not a fan of using `locals()` since it might give you more trouble than benefits. You can read the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901525/django-template-and-the-locals-trick), and the answer of @AlexMartelli will give you really good insights about the use of `locals()`.