# The meaning of vars() in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In many functions in views.py the is a parameter called vars() that is passed to the render.
I want to know what is the use of this parameter and is it better than passing local variable individually to render?

```
return render(request, 'report.html', vars())
```

Comment: See Python documentation on [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars).

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1901720/2011147) and please don't use `vars()` or `locals()` shortcuts as they may lead to sensitive data leaks and unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`render():`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)  accepts a 3rd argument to be `dictionary`

> **vars():** 
>   Return the `__dict__` attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a `__dict__` attribute.

So we can make use of `vars()` as an argument in `render()`.