# Django display multiple uploaded files

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to display multiple uploaded file URLs but I'm not sure how to do it. I am a form that the users can use to upload multiple files that are working perfectly but now I want to be able to display these files. For instance, a company can have more than one file.

```html
class InternationalCompany(models.Model):
    International_company_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    International_company_Id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    options = (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
    )
    Does_it_have_a_Financial_Dealers_License = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=options, null=True) 
    Register_Office = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Beneficial_owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    Beneficial_owner_id = models.FileField(upload_to='passport/pdf/',null=True)
    expire_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    BO_Phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    BO_Email_Address = models.EmailField(null=True)
    BO_Residential_Address = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.International_company_Name


class SupportDocuments(models.Model):
    Supporting_Documents = models.FileField(upload_to='support_doc/pdf/', null=True)
    internationalcompany = models.ForeignKey(InternationalCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Supporting_Documents.url
```

I try something like this but it only displayed one url of the file instead of the multiple urls for the files that are associate with that company.

```html
{%for company in doc%}
     <tr>
        <td></td>

        <td>{{company.internationalcompany.Beneficial_owner}}</td>
          <td>{{company.Supporting_Documents.url}}</td>

     </tr>

{%endfor%}
```

I have also try out this but it doesn't display anything.

```html
  {%for company in doc.Supporting_Documents.all%}

    {{company.url}}

    
{%endfor%}
```

```html
def supporting_doc(request, company_id):
    doc = SupportDocuments.objects.filter(id=company_id)
    return render(request, 'supporting_doc.html', locals())
```

Comment: could you show your view?

Comment: I have added my view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it might be better to use `context` rather than `locals()` [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901525/django-template-and-the-locals-trick/1901720#1901720)

Second, the way you get the doc queryset is wrong. `id=company_id` The id of `SupportingDocuments` is different from `company_id`. What you really need to do is `internationalcompany.id=company_id`.

so views.py:

```
def supporting_doc(request, company_id):
    documents = SupportDocuments.objects.filter(internationalcompany.id=company_id)
    context = { "documents": documents}

    return render(request, 'supporting_doc.html', context)
```

in template:

```
{% for doc in documents %}
{{ doc.internationalcompany.Beneficial_owner}}
{{ doc.Supporting_Documents }}
{% endfor %}
```

On a side note, it may be better to use all lowercases in fields. This way, it is easy to distinguish fields and models.